# How can I downgrade mysql from 5.6 to 5.5 on MAMP?

Tags: mysql, mamp, downgrade

How can I downgrade mysql from 5.6 to 5.5 on MAMP?
Do I need to install something??

Comment: Dont know, but remember to EXPORT all your databases before you try anything

Comment: Have you read the documentation ? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/downgrading.html

Comment: I would have assumed that it's possible to use multiple versions of MySQL with MAMP Pro just like with PHP, but it doesn't seem to be the case. So Docker to the rescue ...

Comment: Even at the time of posting this question, MySQL 5.6 was more than three years old.... why not use current versions instead of those where the end of support is coming nearer and nearer?

Answer (score 0):

According to MAMP documentation, it is not possible:

«No, you can not upgrade or downgrade the version of MySQL that comes with MAMP PRO. You must use MySQL 5.7.»

https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-PRO-Mac/FAQ/MySQL/Can-I-use-MySQL-5.6-with-MAMP-PRO-6/